# Unable to get connect-livereload to work with express server in gulp task

Tags: node.js, express, yeoman, gulp, livereload

I am working off of Yeoman's [gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) generator.  I have modified my `gulp serve` task to use my Express server, rather than the default connect server it ships with. My issue is with Livereload functionality.  I am trying to simply port the connect-livereload to work with my Express server rather than having to install new dependencies.  It's to my understanding that most connect middleware should work fine with Express, so I am assuming connect livereload is compatible with Express 4.

Here are the contents of the relevant tasks in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('express', function() {
  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
  var app = require('./server/app');
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}))
    .use(serveStatic('.tmp'));

  app.listen(3000);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['express'], function () {
  $.livereload.listen();

  // watch for changes
  gulp.watch([
    'app/*.ejs',
    '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*'
  ]).on('change', $.livereload.changed);

  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.css', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);
});

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/main.css')
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'));
});

gulp.task('serve', ['express', 'watch'], function () {
  require('opn')('http://localhost:3000');
});
```

With this simple setup, when I run `gulp serve` in my cmd everything spins up fine and I can accept requests at http://localhost:3000.

Now if I go and change the body's background color from `#fafafa` to `#f00` in main.css and hit save, my gulp output will respond with `main.css was reloaded`, as seen in the bottom of this screenshot.

[image: CMD]

However, my webpage does not update.  The background color is still light-grey instead of red.

Is there perhaps a conflict between my express server config and the way gulp handles its files?  Is my Express server forcing the use of `app/styles/main.css` rather than the use of `.tmp/styles/main.css`?  Shouldn't the livereload script handle the injection of the new temporary file?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I was able to move forward a bit by adding livereload.js to the script block of my index file, like so:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

I am now able to get live changes pushed to the client.  Why was this file not getting injected before?  How can I ensure this is getting used programatically as opposed to pasting it into my files?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this issue by removing the `app.use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}))` from my gulpfile, along with a couple of other lines, and having that instantiate in my Express server's app.js file.

My gulpfile's `express` task now looks like this:

```
gulp.task('express', function() {
  var app = require('./server/app');
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

I added in the `connect-livereload` just above where I specify my static directory in Express:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app')));
```

Once I started using this setup, I was getting the livereload.js script injected into my document, and client-side changes are now auto-refreshed just how I wanted.

Hope this helps someone!